# Custom Workflow won't auto start, but only for one user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, wss

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007 and Sharepoint WSS 3.0 (I know, time for an upgrade).

Anyways, I have a workflow developed in Designer 2007 that simply populates a field in the relevant item with a link. The work is set to start automatically on creation of a new item, and it works perfectly-- with the exception of ONE user (let's call her Lisa).

Everyone else see the resulting link from the workflow, but for Lisa nothing happens at all- i.e. the workflow never fires.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going on. It seemed like it could be a permissions problem, but I checked and Lisa has the exact same permissions as everyone else. Her account is not a System account for sure and is the same as everyone else (besides admin).

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Would completing deleting Lisa's account from the Sharepoint site and re-adding her do anything?

Comment: Is there any event receivers associated with that list?

Comment: no, i don't believe so...